# Points moving towards the nearest point, where will they meet?

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems

> Consider an arbitrary number of distinct points in some $n$
>   dimensional space whose locations are exactly known. Every point is
>   moving towards its nearest point simultaneously, at constant speed. If
>   multiple points meet in a point, that's the new single point and the
>   game continues.  What will be the final point where all the points
>   will eventually meet?
>
> What are the methods to finding the final meeting point?

What if a point is equidistant to multiple points? Then it moves towards all of them :

If a point is equally distant from two points, it moves towards the line determined by those two points. If a point is equally distant from three points, it moves towards the plane determined by those three points. Similarly for more equidistant points in some $n$-space.

---

$(n=1)$

If we are observing points on a line, then if $T(x_1)$ and $T'(x_2)$ are the outmost points (all other points are on the line segemtn $TT'$), then the final point will always be in the midpoint $P(\frac{x_1+x_2}2)$, no matter how many points and where are located on that line segment.

For the cases when a point is equally distant from two closest points, it simply won't move as it is already on the line determined by those two points, which now will meet at it.

$(n>1)$

If we are observing points on a plane, if three points are equally distant from one another, then they will end up in the center of that equilateral triangle, made of those three points. (Since each is moving towards opposing side)

But already at three points on a plane, if we have a pair of points meeting in the middle, and a third point far away gravitating towards one of those two points, its path will be a curve until the two distant points meet, and then its path will continue in a straight line towards the merged point.

[image]

I'm not sure how to show where exactly the final point will end up relative to the triangle. 
(white point on the picture is the meeting point; blue points are the starting points.)

However, if the third point $C$ is equally distant from the two paired points $A,B$, then it is simple to find the ending point as we don't have curved paths. The paired points will meet at the midpoint $P$ of $AB$, and $C$ would've traveled distance $AB/2$ towards $P$ by this point, to $C'$. Now final point is at the midpoint of $PC'$.

> But I'm just observing certain cases and not sure how to approach this
>   generally; as I'm already not sure how to handle arbitrary amount of points on arbitrary locations in the plane.

Example of paths; Random $20$ points on a plane, where red point is $(0,0)$ and white point is the point where all points eventually meet:

[image]

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem? Very interesting without doubt, so I would like to know the applications.

Comment: First thing to think about: Consider two points that are mutual nearest neighbours. (There is at least one such pair.) In the absence of other points, their trajectory is easy to predict, as they simply move towards each other in a straight line. In the *presence* of other points, is it possible for one of them to become "distracted" by a third point passing by? I expect not, but I don't see a proof off the top of my head.

Comment: @YuriyS Just curious how could one formulate some efficient way of predicting the final meeting point. I was also wondering if there were similar, useful problems, as I haven't thought about things similar to this one before.

Comment: A similar problem would be to position identical objects in space and let their gravitational attraction move them.  The objects should be such  that they join on contact and not bounce.  It would not replicate the constant speed.  For two bodies it would result in the same final position but not quite so clear in the general case.  An analytic solution may be difficult as  the general case of objects moving under gravity cannot be solved when there are more than two bodies.

Comment: I doubt there's an analytical solution, especially in higher dimensions. As for simulations, at some point as the sample size / dimension grows, you would have to switch to discrete space / time.

Comment: What happens in this model, if there are more than 2 equidistant points?, like in tetrahedron? (in which case all points are equidistant with more than 2). Otherwise you can get a very good lower and upper bound estimates on convergence time (i.e. no more than half sum of shortest edges for each node in graph)

Comment: @dEmigOd I believe the case of more equidistant points is explained right under the question. If a point is equidistant from 3 other points, it moves towards the plane those points define. So, in a tetrahedron, all points would move towards the opposing side until they meet in the middle.

Comment: For equidistance, suggest rule that the move will be toward center of gravity. If a point is in this center - it is not moving. All other points will converge to this center. May be use some simulations to get a filling what happens. With above rule may be you could show the motion converges to center of gravity (?). May be with other rules you will get convergence to other points.

Comment: Why you assume they are converging to a single location? You need to assume that two points that collide are merged - if not they will remain close to each other. I can envision a case of 4 points that will converge to two locations for each TWO points.

Answer (score 2):

*Solution for $n = 3$ (that can be extended partially)*

Label the points $A,B$ and $C$ such that $\overline{AB} < \overline{AC} < \overline{BC}$ and move them such that $A = (0,0)$. Transform the coordinates for $B = (b_x,b_y) \mapsto (0,1)$

$$T = \pmatrix{b_y & b_x \\ -b_x & b_y} \qquad T^{-1} \cdot C = \pmatrix{x_0 \\ y_0}$$

$\hspace{4cm}$ [image]

$A$ and $B$ will meet at $(0,0.5)$. According to [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PursuitCurve.html) $C$ will have moved to the following coordinates

$$c_x = x_0 \sqrt{\frac{1}{k} \operatorname{W} \left( k \exp{\left( k - \frac{2}{r_0 - y_0} \right)} \right)} \qquad k = \frac{r_0 + y_0}{r_0 - y_0} \quad r_0 = \sqrt{x_0^2 + y_0^2}$$
$$c_y = \frac{1}{4} \left( (y_0 + r_0) \left( \frac{c_x}{x_0} \right)^2 + 2 \, (y_0 - r_0) \ln{\left( \frac{c_x}{x_0} \right)} + 3y_0 - r_0 \right)$$

We then transform back to obtain the coordinates of the final point

$$T \cdot \left[ \frac{1}{2} \pmatrix{c_x \\ c_y + 0.5} \right] = \pmatrix{x \\ y}$$

This also applies to $n = 4$ if there are two pairs of points that don't influence each other

$\hspace{4cm}$ [image]